# Understanding the proof of an equivalent condition for a graph to be a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-connectivity

I am studying graph theory from the book of Harary. There is a proof given in the book for the following:

**If G is a connected graph and $p=q+1$ then G is acyclic, where, $p$= No. of points in the graph and $q$= No. of lines in the graph.**

Proof given is as follows:

*Assume that G has a cycle of length $n$. Then there are $n$ points and $n$ lines on the cycle and for each of the $p-n$ points not on the cycle, there is an incident line on a geodesic to a point of the cycle. Each such line is different, so, $q\ge p$, which is a contradiction.*

I am facing difficulty in understanding the proof since it is too brief for me to understand. Can anyone explain me the line **For each of the $p-n$ points not on the cycle, there is an incident line on a geodesic to a point of the cycle. Each such line is different.**
I have just started with the basic definitions of graph and a few of its properties. It will be helpful if someone explains the above proof with an example pictorially.
Thankyou for the help!

Comment: You need to tell us exactly where you are stuck and why you think that step doesn't work. If If you see a brief proof, try to fill in the details first. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @trisct I have edited my question and clarifired my doubt

Comment: Consider any point not on the cycle. Since the original graph is connected, there must be some path which connects this point to the cycle. So for each point not in the cycle there must be atleast one unique edge added to the current graph (if we start with only the cycle). Hence no. of edges $\geq (p - n) + n \geq q$ which is a contradiction.